# Simplify the following Boolean phrases by using the Boolean basic algebra statements

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Simplify the following Boolean phrases by using the Boolean basic algebra statements:

$(ac)+(bc)+(!ab)$ to the expression $(ac)+(!ab)$.

Answer (score 1):

From 
$$BC=(A+A')BC=ABC+A'BC=(AC+A'B)BC,$$
we get
\begin{align}
AC+BC+A'B
&=AC+BC(AC+A'B)+A'B\\
&=AC(1+BC)+A'B(1+BC)\\
&=AC+A'B.
\end{align}